# Wordpress contact-form Style drop-down font color

Tags: css, colors, background-color, contact-form, dropdown

I created a contact form at the bottom.

see: [http://marketing-für-immobilien.de/wohnung-haus-verkaufen-roth](http://marketing-f%C3%BCr-immobilien.de/wohnung-haus-verkaufen-roth)

On the left side, the last element is a drop-down. When you open it, the words are white, because I changed the color of the contact form

```
.wpcf7-form {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

But unfortunately the drop down maybe adopt the white color. The hover works perfectly. But the color before hovering is white because the background is white.

Is there a possibility to change the color of the `dropdown` to `hex: 002060`?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results .active-result {
    color: #002060;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: thats great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign an id to the select element then just do:

```
#myId
{
    color: #002060;
}
```

Comment: that´s what i tried but i did not work.

yes i can add an id

i tried

#testid {
    color: #002060;
}

The code for the drop-down is:

[textarea your-message class:form-control id:testid placeholder "Nachricht"]

Comment: i mean [select* menu-107 id:testid include_blank "Haus" "Wohnung" "Grundstück"]